# Android: Passing values to another activity's function and then to Sqlite database

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-sqlite

It's been a month since I've kicked off with android studio, at this time I'm stuck at a point where I have to pass a set of `<EditText/>` values from `MainActivity` to `UpdateActivity` and then send those values to the Sqlite database for updating a table.

What I have accomplished:

Successfully sending values from `MainActivity`'s `<EditText/>` to `UpdateActivity`'s `<EditText/>`

How I have done that from `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editName, editSurname, editMarks;
    Button btnUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UpdName);
    editSurname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);
    editMarks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.UpdMarks);
    btnUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String MainName = editName.getText().toString();
            String MainSurname = editSurname.getText().toString();
            String MainMarks = editMarks.getText().toString();

            Intent UpdateAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateActivity.class);
            UpdateAct.putExtra("Name", MainName);
            UpdateAct.putExtra("SurName",MainSurname );
            UpdateAct.putExtra("Marks", MainMarks);
            startActivity(UpdateAct);
        }
    });
}
```

Then inside the `UpdateActivity`:

```
public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
Button btnUpd;
EditText editTextId, editUpdtName, editUpdSurname, editUpdMarks;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

    Intent getData = getIntent();
    String Name = getData.getStringExtra("Name");
    String SurName = getData.getStringExtra("SurName");
    String Marks = getData.getStringExtra("Marks");

    editTextId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextID);
    editUpdtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UpdName);
    editUpdSurname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UpdSurname);
    editUpdMarks = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UpdMarks);
    btnUpd = (Button)findViewById(R.Id.btnUpd);

    editUpdtName.setText(Name);
    editUpdSurname.setText(SurName);
    editUpdMarks.setText(Marks);
}
```

What I'm stuck at is to send these values to a function named `updateData();`
For that I have tried to use the values from `MainActivity` directly to `UpdateActivity` but failed, then I tried to cast those `<EditText/>` and use it inside the function but failed again.

Inside my `UpdateActivity`:

```
..//    
        editUpdtName.setText(Name);
        editUpdSurname.setText(SurName);
        editUpdMarks.setText(Marks);
        //updateData(Name, SurName, Marks);
        updateData();
    }

//function definiton
//   public void updateData(final String Name, final String SurName, final String Marks)
    public void updateData()
    {
        btnUpd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//             boolean isUpdated =   myDb.updateData(editTextId.getText().toString(), Name,SurName, Marks);
                boolean isUpdated =   myDb.updateData(editTextId.getText().toString(), editUpdtName.getText().toString(),
                        editUpdSurname.getText().toString(), editUpdMarks.getText().toString());
            if(isUpdated == true){
                Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Data Updated Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                    Toast.makeText(UpdateActivity.this, "Data NOT Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
        });
    }
}
```

The app crashes everytime the function `updateData();` is called, to ensure that is the real cause I have even commented and also tried putting it in a handler to run it after 3000ms, as expcted it crashed after the time period.

**Solved it by initializing the db.**

`myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/6296561 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/6296561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `myDb`.
Initialize it in your `onCreate()` method:

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

Comment: Okay. And what about `myDb`? Do you initialize it?

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that! I did like a tons of other things to fixed it but ignored the minor little fact of Initializing the `myDb`  -.-

Comment: Happens! Happy coding!

Comment: As per my experience, those are for **missing logcat** in the question. *My app crashes*, doesn't give anything to find a solution, so always post the error logcat as it helps in figuring out what the exact error is.

Comment: I was going to add logcat but solved it by intializig it already so I did not! Any ways thank you for the help man :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the values to `updateData()`?

```
editUpdtName.setText(Name);
editUpdSurname.setText(SurName);
editUpdMarks.setText(Marks);
updateData(Name, SurName, Marks);
```

Comment: I tried that as well. It crashes!

Comment: Then please attach the stack trace to your question.

Comment: have you initialized btnUpd? I can not see this in your onCreate()

Comment: @Chris623 yes I have!

Comment: ok but what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

have you initialized btnUpd? I can not see this in your onCreate()

```
btnUpd = (Button) findViewById(...)
```